# this code does not insert data to database and there is no error or exception?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-insert

```vb
connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ERSAD;Integrated Security=True")
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Transaction_info] (td, uid, datetime, _from, _to, type, femp, semp, fcash, scash, dn, cid, value, newValue, usedValue, damagedValue) 
                    VALUES 
                    (@td, @uid, @datetime, @_from, @_to, @type, @femp, @semp, @fcash, @scash, @dn, @cid, @value, @newValue, @usedValue, @damagedValue);", connection)

For i = 1 To TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 2
    Dim ctrl As List(Of Control) = New List(Of Control)
    For j = TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount - 1 To 0 Step -1

        ctrl.Add(TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(j, i))
        'MessageBox.Show(ctrl.ElementAt(Math.Abs(j - (TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount - 1))).Name.ToString)

    Next j
    If ctrl.ElementAt(0).Text = "" Then
        Continue For
    End If

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@td", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(Label55.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", DbType.Int32).Value = login.id
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", DbType.DateTime).Value = CDate(Label46.Text)
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_from", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(GetTBBOpIdByName(Label40))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_to", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox2.SelectedValue)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@femp", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox3.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semp", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox4.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcash", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox5.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scash", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox6.SelectedValue)

    Else

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_from", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_to", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(GetTBBOpIdByName(Label41))

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@femp", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox5.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semp", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox6.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcash", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox3.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scash", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(ComboBox4.SelectedValue)

    End If
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", DbType.Binary).Value = CBool(typeOfOperation)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(TextBox59.Text)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", DbType.Int32).Value = CInt(GetCurrencyIdByName(ctrl.ElementAt(1)))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(ctrl.ElementAt(0).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(ctrl.ElementAt(2).Text)

    If ctrl.ElementAt(3).Text = "" And ctrl.ElementAt(4).Text = "" Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usedValue", DbType.Int64).Value = 0
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@damagedValue", DbType.Int64).Value = 0

    ElseIf ctrl.ElementAt(3).Text <> "" And ctrl.ElementAt(4).Text = "" Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usedValue", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(ctrl.ElementAt(3).Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@damagedValue", DbType.Int64).Value = 0

    ElseIf ctrl.ElementAt(3).Text = "" And ctrl.ElementAt(4).Text <> "" Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usedValue", DbType.Int64).Value = 0
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@damagedValue", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(ctrl.ElementAt(4).Text)
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usedValue", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(ctrl.ElementAt(3).Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@damagedValue", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(ctrl.ElementAt(4).Text)
    End If

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim row As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show(row & " : rows affected")
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try

Next i
```

im trying to save data into a table using sql parameter but after i run the program it dose not save any thing and i did not get an error or exception 
My main problem is that this query is not currently inserting anything into the database, and I haven't the faintest clue why.
I have been working on this for a while so I am hoping I have something pretty stupid and not noticed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get the message "..rows affected" ?? If not then most certainly your code goes on the catch clause where you are swallowing the exception and do nothing, that's why you don't see any error. Try to show an exception message in the catch clause

Comment: Write MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " : Error") in the catch block and paste the error here.

Comment: sir apomene and atk i tried everything the program is running without any exception, and its return -1 row affected

Comment: You're using a *mixed* syntax. `AddWithValue()` should be renamed to `Add()` and `DbType` changed in `SqlDbType`. See the [SqlParameterCollection.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add) method.

Comment: Thank you jimi i will check this